# Jquery - Select $(this) in .css()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do following code:-

```
$('.someclass').css {
  width: Math.round(($(this).parent().width() / $(this).parent().height()) * $(this).parent().parent().width())
}
```

But I have failed to get the result.

Comment: `$(this)` would not be the `someclass` element... Assuming that is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Please edit your question and state what is not working.  *"But I have failed to get the result."* tells us nothing. What happened, what did you expect to happen, what errors appear in the console, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to calculate the value to give to the CSS property based on the current element, you can provide a function to the `css()` method, like this:

```
$('.someclass').css('width', function() {
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  return Math.round(($parent.width() / $parent.height()) * $parent.parent().width())
});
```